# Python: Extract certain elements from file

Tags: python

I have a file which looks like this in short and I'm planing to extract some of the elements from this file to form a new file by using Python 2.7, however here's some problems that I can't deal with. I'm new to programming, hope someone can give me a hand. Thanks in advance!

Sorry for the inconvenience, error caused by the first for loop without defined line. This is another problem, I have to add a print line statement before to make the code work. See below updated code.

```
#File
POS ID  PosScore    NegScore    SynsetTerms Gloss
a   00001740    0.125   0   able#1  (usually followed by `to') having the necessary means or skill or know-how or authority to do something; "able to swim"; "she was able to program her computer"; "we were at last able to buy a car"; "able to get a grant for the project"
a   00014490    0.125   0   rich#12 plentiful#2 plenteous#1 copious#2 ample#2   affording an abundant supply; "had ample food for the party"; "copious provisions"; "food is plentiful"; "a plenteous grape harvest"; "a rich supply"
```

**Task:**

I'm planing to extract three columns from this file and form a new file in this order: SynsetTerms, PosScore, NegScore. I'm using print to test first instead of g.write().

**Problem:**

1.I'm trying to index every element contains'#' in the .split() list and have them printed, but it can't get more than two words.

2.I'm also trying to remove the '#' and the number follows by only printing [:-2] but it does not work for numbers with more than one digit.

3.Must define line in the first step to make the rest of the code work. I was thinking if the first word and it's next word both contains '#', then print both of them.

```
#INPUT1
# Fix previous error: Define 'line'
f = open("senti_test.txt","r")

for line in f:
    print line

f.close()

#INPUT2
f = open("senti_test.txt","r")
g = open("senti_test_new.txt", "w")

for num in xrange(4,len(line.split())):
    for line in f:
        if '#' in line.split()[num] and '#' in line.split()[num + 1]:
            print (line.split()[num][:-2] + '\t' + line.split()[2] + '\t' + line.split()[3] + '\n') + ('\n') + (line.split()[num + 1][:-2] + '\t' + line.split()[2] + '\t' + line.split()[3] + '\n')        
        else:
            print line.split()[4][:-2] + '\t' + line.split()[2] + '\t' + line.split()[3] + '\n'

f.close()
g.close()

#OUTPUT
SynsetTer   PosScore    NegScore

able    0.125   0

rich#   0.125   0

plentiful   0.125   0
```

Comment: Your code fails at the first **for** statement: **line** is undefined.  Your input has no word "plentiful".  Please post the code and input that produced the output you cite.

Comment: What do you mean by "trying to index every element"?  i don't see any indexing here.  I just see that you're printing them much as you did with the main entry.

Comment: Note that you cannot use direct indexing to get rid of the pound & number: as you've noted, you don't know where they are relative to either end of the string.

Comment: @Prune Thanks for the reply, code updated along with question. By indexing I mean get the word which contains '#'. I'll try your suggestion and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Do note the techniques in the answer I supplied below.  I use that split-on-# at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: Yes, that's a very good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that this is much closer to what you want.  I'll let you replace the output file when you have this tuned.

```
f = open("so.txt","r")

for line in f:
    line_split = line.split()      # Split the line on spaces
    pos_score = line_split[2]      # 3rd & 4th columns are the scores
    neg_score = line_split[3]
    for entry in line_split[4:]:   # step through the remainder of the line, looking for words to index
        if '#' in entry:
            # When a word is found, split off the #<num> and print the entry.
            print entry.split('#')[0], pos_score, neg_score

f.close()
```

I changed the pos_score of the second line to 0.140, to help readability.  Here's the output:

```
able 0.125 0
rich 0.140 0
plentiful 0.140 0
plenteous 0.140 0
copious 0.140 0
ample 0.140 0
```

Also note that you can save the index number with a little extra code in the loop:

```
    if '#' in entry:
        # When a word is found, split off the #<num> and print the entry.
        word, idx = entry.split('#')
        print word, pos_score, neg_score, "\tindex=", idx
```

Output:

```
able 0.125 0    index= 1
rich 0.140 0    index= 12
plentiful 0.140 0   index= 2
plenteous 0.140 0   index= 1
copious 0.140 0     index= 2
ample 0.140 0   index= 2
```

Comment: Use with statement, that avoids closing the file by close method

Comment: Right.  However, I try to keep the tech level closer to the OP's level.

Comment: Thanks for the expanded information. I understand that **with** statement is more secure than **open()** and **close()**, but in this case, what is the correct **with** statement expression to open two files at the same time? As I need open one to read and another to write. Thanks